# Google chart sorting disable

Tags: google-visualization

I am using below code to create a google chart where I show the alerts on Y axis and the Months on X axis ,Here I am trying to show data with bar charts and also a trend line for it, issue I am facing is that data  is coming sorted i.e say current month is sep i.e 09 then data is coming on y - axis as from 01 to 12 months, but what I want is data to be placed in the order where 09 is at last i.e current month is last
10 11 12 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09

in the code ticks variable contains value "10 11 12 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
"

```
var options = {
                        title: '<?php echo "Alerts Trend Analysis $TEAM";?>',
                        hAxis: {title: 'MONTH' ,gridlines: { count: 12 },ticks: [ <?php echo $TICKS;?>] },
                        vAxis: {title: 'Alerts'},
                        curveType: 'function',
                        titleFontSize:15,
                        fontName : 'Arial',
                        titleFontName: 'Arial',
                         trendlines: {
                                        0: {type: 'polynomial', lineWidth: 2, opacity: .5},
                                        1: {type: 'polynomial', lineWidth: 2, opacity: .5},
                                        2: {type: 'polynomial', lineWidth: 2, opacity: .5},
                                        3: {type: 'polynomial', lineWidth: 2, opacity: .5},
                                        4: {type: 'polynomial', lineWidth: 2, opacity: .5}
                                     },

                        series: {
                        0: { color: 'green' },
                        1: { color: 'orange' },
                        2: { color: 'blue' },
                        3: { color: 'red' },
                        4: { color: 'purple' },
                        5: { color: 'black' }
                        },
                        legend: { position: 'right',textStyle: {fontSize: 12}}
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
                }
```

The data I am using from a csv file to upload in the variables

```
VHPLUSLIVE,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,4:0:0:1:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,4:0:0:1:0:0:0
VHPLUSQA,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:1:0:0:0,22:3:0:5:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,22:3:0:6:0:0:0
VHLIVE,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:1:0:0,18:5:0:4:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,18:5:0:4:1:0:0
LIVE,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,152:17:1:42:2:0:0,197:28:2:66:2:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,349:45:3:108:4:0:0
QA,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,28:2:1:7:1:1:0,152:17:0:36:0:3:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,180:19:1:43:1:4:0
TEST,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,7:2:0:4:1:0:0,14:3:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,21:5:0:4:1:0:0
OTHERS,0:0:0:0:0:0:,83:13:0:14:1:0:,49:8:0:13:1:0:,0:0:0:3:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:,132:21:0:30:2:0:0
ALL,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,270:34:2:68:6:1:0,456:64:2:125:3:3:0,0:0:0:3:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,0:0:0:0:0:0:0,726:98:4:201:9:4:0
```

Also , code that I am using to put data in the variables is as below

```
 for ($MONTH=$CURMONTH + 1;$MONTH<=12;$MONTH++)
     {
        if ( $MONTH < 10 )
        {
             $MONTH="0" . $MONTH;
        }
        else
        {
             $MONTH="". $MONTH;
        }


        if ( "$STAT" == "Ack_time" )
        {
        $FILE="/OVO/ALERTS/${TEAM}_${MONTH}.ack.count";
        }
        elseif ( "$STAT" == "Own_time" )
        {
        $FILE="/OVO/ALERTS/${TEAM}_${MONTH}.own.count";
        }

        $filer=fopen("${FILE}","r");
        $pattern="/\b$Env\b/";
                while (!feof($filer))
                {
                        $line = fgets($filer);
                        if (preg_match("$pattern", $line, $match))
                        {
                                $line=explode(",",$line);
                                break;
                        }
                }
                fclose($filer);

                if ( "$Criticity" == "Critical" )
                {
                        $line=$line[1];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Major" )
                {
                        $line=$line[2];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Minor" )
                {
                        $line=$line[3];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Warning" )
                {
                        $line=$line[4];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Normal" )
                {
                        $line=$line[5];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "OTHERS" )
                {
                        $line=$line[6];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "ALL" )
                {
                        $line=$line[7];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }



        $count_8=$line[0];
        $count_24=$line[1];
        $count_48=$line[2];
        $count_120=$line[3];
        $count_240=$line[4];
        $count_480=$line[5];
        $count_rest=$line[6];

        $count_all=$count_8+$count_24+$count_48+$count_120+$count_240+$count_480+$count_rest;



        if ( "$MONTH" == "01" )
        {
                $MON="January";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "02" )
        {
                $MON="February";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "03" )
        {
                $MON="March";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "04" )
        {
                $MON="April";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "05" )
        {
                $MON="May";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "06" )
        {
                $MON="June";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "07" )
        {
                $MON="July";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "08" )
        {
                $MON="August";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "09" )
        {
                $MON="September";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "10" )
        {
                $MON="October";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "11" )
        {
                $MON="November";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "12" )
        {
                $MON="December";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "13" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_1";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "14" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_2";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "15" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_3";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "16" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_4";
        }

        //pushing some variables to the array so we can output something in this example.

                //pushing some variables to the array so we can output something in this example.
        if ( $STAT == "Ack_time" )
        {
        array_push($values, array("MONTH" => "${MONTH}","Ack <8h" => $count_8,"Ack 8h-24h" => $count_24,"Ack 24h-48h" => $count_48,"Ack 48h-120h" => $count_120,"Ack 120h-240h" => $count_240,"Ack 240h-480h" => $count_480,"Ack > 480h" => $count_rest ));
        }

        if ( $STAT == "Own_time" )
        {
        array_push($values, array("MONTH" => "${MONTH}","Own <8h" => $count_8,"Own 8h-24h" => $count_24,"Own 24h-48h" => $count_48,"Own 48h-120h" => $count_120,"Own 120h-240h" => $count_240,"Own 240h-480h" => $count_480,"Own > 480h" => $count_rest ));
        }


    }

    for ($MONTH=01;$MONTH<=$CURMONTH;$MONTH++)
     {
        if ( $MONTH < 10 )
        {
             $MONTH="0" . $MONTH;
        }
        else
        {
             $MONTH="". $MONTH;
        }



        if ( "$STAT" == "Ack_time" )
        {
        $FILE="/OVO/ALERTS/${TEAM}_${MONTH}.ack.count";
        }
        elseif ( "$STAT" == "Own_time" )
        {
        $FILE="/OVO/ALERTS/${TEAM}_${MONTH}.own.count";
        }

        $filer=fopen("${FILE}","r");
        $pattern="/\b$Env\b/";
                while (!feof($filer))
                {
                        $line = fgets($filer);
                        if (preg_match("$pattern", $line, $match))
                        {
                                $line=explode(",",$line);
                                break;
                        }
                }
                fclose($filer);

                if ( "$Criticity" == "Critical" )
                {
                        $line=$line[1];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Major" )
                {
                        $line=$line[2];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Minor" )
                {
                        $line=$line[3];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Warning" )
                {
                        $line=$line[4];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "Normal" )
                {
                        $line=$line[5];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "OTHERS" )
                {
                        $line=$line[6];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }
                elseif ( "$Criticity" == "ALL" )
                {
                        $line=$line[7];
                        $line=explode(":",$line);
                }



        $count_8=$line[0];
        $count_24=$line[1];
        $count_48=$line[2];
        $count_120=$line[3];
        $count_240=$line[4];
        $count_480=$line[5];
        $count_rest=$line[6];

        $count_all=$count_8+$count_24+$count_48+$count_120+$count_240+$count_480+$count_rest;

        //pushing some variables to the array so we can output something in this example.




        if ( "$MONTH" == "01" )
        {
                $MON="January";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "02" )
        {
                $MON="February";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "03" )
        {
                $MON="March";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "04" )
        {
                $MON="April";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "05" )
        {
                $MON="May";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "06" )
        {
                $MON="June";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "07" )
        {
                $MON="July";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "08" )
        {
                $MON="August";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "09" )
        {
                $MON="September";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "10" )
        {
                $MON="October";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "11" )
        {
                $MON="November";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "12" )
        {
                $MON="December";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "13" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_1";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "14" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_2";
        }

        if ( "$MONTH" == "15" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_3";
        }
        if ( "$MONTH" == "16" )
        {
                $MON="Quarter_4";
        }

        //pushing some variables to the array so we can output something in this example.


        if ( $STAT == "Ack_time" )
        {
        array_push($values, array("MONTH" => "${MONTH}","Ack <8h" => $count_8,"Ack 8h-24h" => $count_24,"Ack 24h-48h" => $count_48,"Ack 48h-120h" => $count_120,"Ack 120h-240h" => $count_240,"Ack 240h-480h" => $count_480,"Ack > 480h" => $count_rest ));
        }

        if ( $STAT == "Own_time" )
        {
        array_push($values, array("MONTH" => "${MONTH}","Own <8h" => $count_8,"Own 8h-24h" => $count_24,"Own 24h-48h" => $count_48,"Own 48h-120h" => $count_120,"Own 120h-240h" => $count_240,"Own 240h-480h" => $count_480,"Own > 480h" => $count_rest ));
        }


    }

}


//counting the length of the array
$countArrayLength = count($values);
```

Comment: on small correction the month is on X axis

Comment: HI Whitehat , I am also providing trend lines with the graphs, that I think requires both axes to be numbered only , now the issue I face it with this is that I am not getting current month at the end of graph, Also I have update the code snippets and data in my post , please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you've discovered, the chart will sort a continuous axis in the logical order
this cannot be changed

however, you can use object notation, both in the data table values and the ticks,
to use one value and display another

using object notation, you can provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

for the month numbers, if the first three rows = 10,11,12
the next row needs to be 13

in the data table use...

```
{v: 13, f: '1'}
```

this will allow the give you the order you need, and the tooltip will show `'1'`

to correct the x-axis, the tick for this row would be the same object...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['month', 'alerts'],
    [10, 97],
    [11, 100],
    [12, 80],
    [{v: 13, f: '1'}, 105],
    [{v: 14, f: '2'}, 60],
    [{v: 15, f: '3'}, 88],
    [{v: 16, f: '4'}, 77],
    [{v: 17, f: '5'}, 90],
    [{v: 18, f: '6'}, 67],
    [{v: 19, f: '7'}, 52],
    [{v: 20, f: '8'}, 67],
    [{v: 21, f: '9'}, 80]
  ]);

  var ticks = [
    10, 11, 12,
    {v: 13, f: '1'},
    {v: 14, f: '2'},
    {v: 15, f: '3'},
    {v: 16, f: '4'},
    {v: 17, f: '5'},
    {v: 18, f: '6'},
    {v: 19, f: '7'},
    {v: 20, f: '8'},
    {v: 21, f: '9'}
  ];

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {ticks: ticks},
    trendlines: {0: {}}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

if this is difficult to achieve in php,
use the following snippet to manipulate the data and ticks in JavaScript
note: in this scenario, the data table needs to be in the desired order

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['month', 'alerts'],
    [10, 97],
    [11, 100],
    [12, 80],
    [1, 105],
    [2, 60],
    [3, 88],
    [4, 77],
    [5, 90],
    [6, 67],
    [7, 52],
    [8, 67],
    [9, 80]
  ]);

  var ticks = [];
  var firstMonth;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var rowMonth = data.getValue(i, 0);
    if (i === 0) {
      firstMonth = rowMonth;
    } else {
      if (rowMonth < firstMonth) {
        data.setCell(i, 0, rowMonth + 12, rowMonth.toString());
      }
    }
    ticks.push({
      v: data.getValue(i, 0),
      f: rowMonth.toString()
    });
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {ticks: ticks},
    trendlines: {0: {}}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, trying to plot flu weeks 40-52 followed by 1-39. Google Charts was plotting it 1-52, and looping back around with a straight line from 52 to 1.

I solved it by changing `data.addColumn('number', 'Flu Season Week');` to `data.addColumn('string', 'Flu Season Week');` and providing it with a space-aligned string using Python `return '% 2d' % week`

see the result at https://jc.unternet.net/covid19/. The javascript is in chart2.js and fludata.js.